# Unable to setValue into reactive forms for second time after resetting the form

Tags: angular

Using reactive forms, when we click on edit a particular user using setValue methods am populating into form controls. Then when i click on save button i am clearing the form using reset() method.

Now if click on the edit button for another user i am populating the data same as above, but setValue or patchValue is not adding data into form fields

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzyjig

Comment: Please provide a [mininaml reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzyjig

Comment: So you are saying that your view is not updating?

Comment: I've checked your demo, and it seems that you form is being populated when I click on another name but it is not updating the view when I click on the same name, the second time, after submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

> **Your problem is related to [Change Detection](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/).**

**Problem with your code:**

You are sending the value from parent component to child component and you are calling your `edit` method inside the `ngOnChanges` which will run during Angular Change Detection.

In your parent component `edit` method, you have:

```
edit(user){
   this.user = user;
   console.log(this.user);
}
```

Now if you click on the same user edit button, `this.user` will not change and it will not trigger the `ngOnChanges` method of your child component and your form will not populate.

**Solution:(You can find the working stackbliz demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ut9moq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-form%2Fuser.component.ts)
)**

You need to change the value of the user every time even when you click on the same user edit button and trigger change detection manually.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){
  }

  edit(user){
    this.user = null;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
   this.user = user;
   console.log(this.user);
  }
}
```

Your `ngOnChanges` will look like this:

```
ngOnChanges(){
    if(this.user) {
      this.edit();
    }
  }
```

Comment: ngOnChanges(){
    if(this.editableProduct){
      this.EditProductData();
    }
  }                                                                                                        
    EditProductData(){
    
    if(!!this.editableProduct && !!this.editableProduct.productToEdit){
      this.PDForm.patchValue({
        productIDName: this.editableProduct.productToEdit.productIDName,
        moq: this.editableProduct.productToEdit.moq
      })
    }
  }

Comment: In EditProductDatamethod i am getting this.editableProduct data, but it is not populating the data into form fields for the second time.